# TinyMCE replacing < with &lt;

Tags: javascript, python, django, textbox, tinymce

I'm running Django with placeholder tags:

I'm trying to add a flash video into my TinyMCE edidtor but it keeps replacing the '<' with < in the code causing it not work load and just show the code.

I have also tried creating a Textarea with the Django CMS as a extra HTML box to see if it was the editor but it's doing the same thing in the textarea.

Thanks.

Comment: It'll be escaping the content, have a poke about in the manual pages for how to turn off escaping. Although be aware of the security issues of not cleansing your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of placeholders is that you can stack them, so why not  put a separate [Flash plugin](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-cms/en/2.1.3/getting_started/plugin_reference.html#flash) or [Snippet plugin](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/getting_started/plugin_reference.html#snippet) below your Text plugin and then continue with a second Text plugin below.

To install either of those plugins (which are included with django-cms), just add them to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'cms.plugins.snippet',
'cms.plugins.flash',
...
)
```

Comment: The reason why were not hosting is because were using embeded code so it's already hosted on another site. Thanks for your reply though I will look into this but you can think of a way in doing without having to install this app that would be great.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. Well there is a [`Snippet`](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-cms/en/2.1.3/getting_started/plugin_reference.html#snippet) plugin too you could use (if it's already installed) which allows for plain HTML. That's an alternative if you can't get TinyMCE to escape

Comment: That looks like it's the sort of thing I need..I'm new to Django what else would i need to do to install the Snippet App?.. Thanks again

Comment: You simply need to include `cms.plugins.snippet` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py` file and the `Snippet` plugin will show up in the dropdown list when adding a plugin to a placeholder

Comment: Thanks for your help, the issue we have here is I think we use the djagno-page-cms rather than the django-cms package. Would this have any effect?

Answer (score -1):

Was an issue the settings.py file, there was a line of code missing.